# How to suppress Error printed by shell commands.

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am writing an Script(BASH script), which uses `dpkg, rpm, pacman` commands, but at a time for a os one command is applicable, these command will run in different OS so for some os dpkg will pop up the error, is there any way to not let print the error while running this script ?
am i clear ?
`./test_package.sh: line 20: rpm: command not found`
i want to suppress this error.

Comment: You can redirect stderr to `dev/null` --> `2 > /dev/null`.

Comment: It's better to check if a command exists first.

[Here's a related question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script